# ¿Como agregar y eliminar marcador de google-maps en javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic

¿como agregar un marcador en google-maps y eliminar al mantener seleccionado por 5 segundos.?

```
  function genera_marcador(lat, lng) {
        var marcador = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            draggable: true,
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });
    };
```

Comment: saludos German, siento que andas aprendiendo sobre google maps, te recomiendo llevar este tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/google_maps/ espero te sea de utilidad. Bienvenido al sitio de SOes :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google maps no tiene un almacén global de los features que dibujas en el mapa. Queda a tu cargo guardar esa referencia. Por ejemplo si retornas el marker que creas

```
function genera_marker (lat,lng) {
    ...
    return marcador;
}
```

Y lo declaras como

```
var mimarker = genera_marker (10,10);
```

Después puedes borrarlo con

```
mimarker.setMap ( null );
```

Lo mismo corre para círculos, polígonos, rectángulos y polilíneas.